# casperjs select not working for angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, automated-tests, html-select, casperjs

Tried all solutions given in [How to fill a select element which is not embedded in a form with CasperJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515292/how-to-fill-a-select-element-which-is-not-embedded-in-a-form-with-casperjs/28515450#28515450)   and tried many more links. 
Situation is this that I can not change code below to add any additional attribute and jquery or javascript solutions to select any option are not working.

```
<select class="form-control mg-dn ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-model="instance.order.fk_physician_id" ng-required="true" required="required">
    <option value="" selected="">Select Physician</option>
    <!-- ngRepeat: doc in instance.doctors -->
    <option ng-repeat="doc in instance.doctors" value="669" class="ng-binding ng-scope">fJensik Jensik</option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: doc in instance.doctors -->
    <option ng-repeat="doc in instance.doctors" value="660" class="ng-binding ng-scope">fHillman Hillman</option>

<!-- end ngRepeat: doc in instance.doctors --></select>
```

Tried these code solutions

1. ```
   casper.fillSelectors('div#order-details', {
       'select[ng-model="instance.order.fk_physician_id"]': '669'
   }, false);
   ```
2. ```
   casper.evaluate(function(){
       document.querySelector('select[ng-model="instance.order.fk_physician_id"]').focus();
   });
   this.page.sendEvent('keypress', this.page.event.key.Down);`
   ```
3. ```
   casper.selectOptionByValue = function(selector, valueToMatch){
       this.evaluate(function(selector, valueToMatch){
           var select = document.querySelector(selector),
               found = false;
           Array.prototype.forEach.call(select.children, function(opt, i){
               if (!found && opt.value.indexOf(valueToMatch) !== -1) {
                   select.selectedIndex = i;
                   found = true;
               }
           });
           // dispatch change event in case there is some kind of validation
           var evt = document.createEvent("UIEvents"); // or "HTMLEvents"
           evt.initUIEvent("change", true, true);
           select.dispatchEvent(evt);
       }, selector, valueToMatch);
   };
   casper.start(url, function() {
       this.selectOptionByValue('select[ng-model="instance.order.fk_physician_id"]', "669");
   }).run();
   ```
4. ```
   $('select[ng-model="instance.order.fk_physician_id"] option:nth-child(3)').prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
   ```
5. ```
   $('select[ng-model="instance.order.fk_physician_id"]').val("669").change();
   ```

Anyone, Please suggest some workable solution.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: I'm using phantomjs version 2.1.1

Comment: Are you sure that the select box is populated when you're trying to select an option?

Comment: Console: WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
ResourceError: {
    "errorCode": 5,
    "errorString": "Operation canceled",
    "id": 130,
    "status": null,
    "statusText": null,
    "url": "http://api.caremerge.loc/facilities/105/residents/52301/medications/doctors"
}
Console: HTTP Request Failed

Comment: I'm checking with waitUntilVisible for option:nth-child(3) then performing operations on option

`casper.waitUntilVisible(map.physicianOrderAddScreen.physicianFieldOption, function() {

                helper.clickOn("Physcians List Options", map.physicianOrderAddScreen.physicianFieldOption, 25000);

                    });`

Comment: trying this as well 
`casper.sendKeys(map.physicianOrderAddScreen.physicianField, '669');`

Comment: and casper.evaluate(function (physicianFieldOption){
    $(physicianFieldOption).prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
// and 
$("select[ng-model='instance.order.fk_physician_id']").val("669").change();
},  map.physicianOrderAddScreen.physicianFieldOption)

Comment: __utils__.echo($('select[ng-model="instance.order.fk_physician_id"]').val()); 
echoes null

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the select box is populated when I'm trying to select an option.

Comment: `casper.waitUntilVisible("select[ng-model='instance.order.fk_physician_id'] option:nth-child(3)", function() {

                    casper.test.pass("Physcians List Options loads in given time.");

                    helper.clickOn("Physcians List Options", "select[ng-model='instance.order.fk_physician_id'] option:nth-child(3)", 25000);

                    }, function(){

                    casper.test.fail("Physcians List Options did not load in gicen time.");

                }, 20000);`

Above code is showing 
"PASS Physcians List Options loads in given time" in terminal when I run test.

Comment: @ArtjomB. please check above comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its work for me

```
casper.capture('before-select.png');
var nameInScope='instance.order.fk_physician_id';
var value=669;//but i'm not sure your data structure (value is a number?)
casper.evaluate(function (nameInScope, value) {
    if (typeof value == 'number') {
        value = 'number:' + value;
    }
    //TODO all types

    var selectedIndex = $('select[ng-model="' + nameInScope + '"] option[value="' + value + '"]').index();
    var theSelect = $('select[ng-model="' + nameInScope + '"]').get(0);
    theSelect.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
    $(theSelect).blur();//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136361/how-to-select-an-option-with-casperjs
}, {
    nameInScope: nameInScope, value: value
});
casper.capture('after-select.png');
```